# Hide xtitle but keep ticklabels in dash plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to delete the `date` legend on my line chart but keep the `ticklabels`. Here's how I'm doing the `fig.update` but that seemed to delete both.

```
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False, showticklabels=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=.25, gridcolor='#DCDCDC')
```

[image]

Here's my ideal result. [image]

How do I write the `fig.update` to get my ideal output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating the X-Axis, you could write this:

```
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='', showticklabels=True)
```